# Reverting OpenBSD Install In-Place

Tags: upgrade, openbsd, bsd, vps

What I'm trying to do is revert my VPS running OpenBSD-current (following via binary updates, using snapshots and booting to ramdisk) to OpenBSD-6.2-release.

It's not an important system, so if it gets borked, I'll start over. However, I'd like to not set it up from scratch because I *do* use it.

If I boot to ramdisk (boot: bsd.rd), then follow the upgrade process, however, I replace the path to the new -current image with the path to the 6.2-release image, will I have many problems? Following that, I would obviously change PKG_PATH to reflect the change to -release, and update the packages accordingly.

I'm assuming I won't have many problems, even if this is not advised and not supported, because I'm not jumping major version numbers (ie. current has not advanced to -6.3 yet, so it's essentially "upgrading" to an older binary snapshot of -6.2)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got impatient and just did it.

It went seamlessly. I just booted to bsd.rd, like the standard update process for -current, but replaced the path with the 6.2-release images.

Upon reboot everything started up fine. I updated PKG_PATH to reflect the change for packages. Everything's good there.

Now running syspatch to get the necessary patches.

I imagine this might not have gone smoothly if I had traversed version numbers, ie, gone from 6.3 to 6.2. Luckily it was 6.2 to 6.2.

Comment: Well, you did something that certainly is _not_ supported, no matter what the version numbers are, and you were pretty lucky it worked. There is no supported way of downgrading from a snapshot (or -current) build to a -release or -stable build. Sometimes it may work.

Comment: See [the following -current FAQ](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/current.html) for changes that may have been in your -current system that were reverted by your downgrading to 6.2-release.

Comment: you may also want to try `sysclean` from ports to see what it finds

Comment: The only reason I even attempted it was because, while I use this VPS, it isn't *important* so I could stand to lose it and start over. Thanks for the heads up with sysclean, I'll do that now.

Comment: I initially made a poor decision to follow -current with the VPS. It became a burden to do so and I wished to move to the traditional OpenBSD maintenance cycle of patching errata, only upgrading on new releases, etc.